# Coherent schemes generated by global sections on a Noetherian Scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This question arises from the proof of proposition 7.10 in Hartshorne chapter II. Here, we have a Noetherian scheme $X$ and a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules which is generated by global sections. Hartshorne claims that $\mathcal{F}$ can in fact be generated by finitely many global sections.

How do we see that? Since $X$ is Noetherian and $\mathcal{F}$ we have a finite affine opening such that $\mathcal{F}|_U \cong \tilde{M}$ for some finitely generatered module $M$ over a Noetherian ring $A_i$.  How does this lead us to conclude $\mathcal{F}$ is globally generated by finitely many elements? This is the furthest I can go. Any help given would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick a finite number of generators of $M_i$ as an $A_i$ module. Since the restrictions of global sections generate $M_i$, we can write each generator of $M_i$ as a finite $A_i$-linear sum of the global generators (this works because we can only consider finite sums!). Thus we get a finite list of global generators which suffice to generate $M_i$. Now take the union of the lists for each $M_i$ across all elements of your finite cover, and you get a finite list of global generators for your global sheaf.

Comment: Oh my thank you! Can't believe I let this slip.